# SQL structure to count size of a queue through changes over time

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-structures

How can I design an SQL data structure that will let me query how large a queue was (how many records) over time (so I can graph it), when the items constantly move from queue to queue.

Tables:

```
Queue
--------------------------------------
item_id      int
status       enum('new','ready','old')

Log
--------------------------------------
item_id      int
old_status   enum('new','ready','old')  --perhaps record new_status instead?--
change_date  timestamp
```

Every time an item changes status (i.e. new queue) I record it in the log.

How can I write a query that tells me "At 10:00 there were X records in 'new', and Y in 'ready', etc". And do this throughout the day so I can graph it.

I don't want to make a table with the totals every 5 minutes because I don't know my timing granularity ahead of time.

I'm perfectly willing to change the database structure, and add new fields to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

If the log recorded both the new status and the old status, you could add new pseudo columns to the table that act as increment and decrement counters for each status:

```
SELECT 
    l.change_date
    CASE WHEN l.new_status = 'new'   THEN 1 WHEN l.old_status = 'new'   THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS new_count
    CASE WHEN l.new_status = 'ready' THEN 1 WHEN l.old_status = 'ready' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS ready_count
    CASE WHEN l.new_status = 'old'   THEN 1 WHEN l.old_status = 'old'   THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS old_count
  FROM log l
  ORDER BY l.change_date
```

Summing the pseudo columns up to a particular date should leave you with a count of what was active at that date. An analytic SUM function sounds like the right tool.  This assumes the old state and new state are never the same. Perhaps you can apply something like that.

Comment: This requires me to run the query from the start of the log - otherwise entries from a long time ago, that are still in a status would not be counted. I'm worried that's going to be too slow.

Comment: Yes, it would be a full scan for the running total if used with an analytic function. Perhaps not appropriate for your use case. But at least not a scan for each data point. Depending on the accuracy you require, and the nature of the data, you might be able to start from an intermediate time and count changes from that time, or introduce expiries to create bounds. If you store running totals you have the continuous update cost and will need to run periodic sanity checks.

Answer (score 1):

If you think querying the `log` table would be costly, you can make a snapshot table, which will capture the number of records in each queue for example every day. At the end of each day insert new rows to this table. So to find out the numbers in any time, you can just apply the changes during this time in that day to the snapshot taken at the end of previous day. If you index the `change_date` column in the `log` table, this query will run pretty fast i think.